# KeyError:［］not found in axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
X = data.iloc[:,1:4]
enc = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto').fit(X)
result = enc.transform(X).toarray()
result
enc.get_feature_names()
newdata = pd.concat([data,pd.DataFrame(result)],axis=1)
newdata.columns
```

显示结果为Index([       '总里程',       '业务类型',      '需求类型1',      '需求类型2',  '线路价格（不含税）'，……，0,            1,            2,
                  3,            4,            5],
      dtype='object')，以上都正常

```
newdata.drop(['业务类型','需求类型1','需求类型2'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-dda56039a1d9> in <module>
----> 1 newdata.drop(['业务类型','需求类型1','需求类型2'],axis=1,inplace=True)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   4100             level=level,
   4101             inplace=inplace,
-> 4102             errors=errors,
   4103         )
   4104 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3912         for axis, labels in axes.items():
   3913             if labels is not None:
-> 3914                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
   3915 
   3916         if inplace:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors)
   3944                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
   3945             else:
-> 3946                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
   3947             result = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   3948 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   5338         if mask.any():
   5339             if errors != "ignore":
-> 5340                 raise KeyError("{} not found in axis".format(labels[mask]))
   5341             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   5342         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: "['业务类型' '需求类型1' '需求类型2'] not found in axis"
```

请问哪里出错了？

Comment: Are 'A', 'B', and 'C' in the DataFrame's columns? This error is suggesting that they're not. Please post a sample of your dataframe (e.g. the result of `df.head()` so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: Ok. `df.drop(columns_list, axis=1)` does work to drop columns in the dataframe. You must have an error somewhere else. Can you post the [full stacktrace](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/) so we can understand what's going wrong? To get the best help, see this post on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the edits. It could be the version... what version of pandas are you running? check with `pd.__version__`

Comment: You should be fine with 0.25.1. The latest stable version is [1.0.4](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/index.html), so this will have the most features and various bug fixes, but 0.25.1 is a very recent release and `df.drop` definitely works in this relese. If you're still having trouble, we'll need a valid [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can actually execute to understand what the issue is. If you're able to provide a full, testable example that demonstrates the issue that would be really helpful!